# unix sqlplus call doesnt return control sometimes

Tags: oracle, session, unix, sqlplus

I am facing one issue, which I am trying to fix for sometime.

I have a shell script, which calls a pl/sql stored procedure using sqlplus. Most of the time it runs fine, but the script becomes idle(S) waiting for the procedure to be completed. When I investigated, the procedure has been completed successfully at oracle end, and the session is also complete, but the control has not been given back to sqlplus/shell script, which is why it is waiting. Can someone guide me how to crack this issue.

```
RESULT=`sqlplus  user/pwd@ip/servicename <<EOF
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
   spool out.log;
   CALL schmea.package.proc
   quit;
EOF`;
```

Comment: How long does the procedure call take, and is there a cut-off where a longer time seems to cause this? Wondering if the session or connection is being killed - by Oracle or the network - and SQL\*Plus and/or the shell doesn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank line after "QUIT".
And, this is unrelated but remove the semicolon after SQLPlus commands (set serverutput, quit, spool)